# Dynamically-created 'zip' command not excluding directories properly

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sh

I'm the author of a utilty that makes compressing projects using `zip` a bit easier, especially when you have to compress regularly, such as for updating projects submitted to an application store (like Chrome's Web Store).

I'm attempting to make quite a few improvements, but have run into an issue, described below.

**A Quick Overview**
My utility's command format is similar to `command OPTIONS DEST DIR1 {DIR2 DIR3 DIR4...}`. It works by running `zip -r DEST.zip DIR1`; a fairly simple process. The benefit to my utility, however, is the ability to use a predetermined file (think `.gitignore`) to ignore specific files/directories, or files/directories which match a pattern.

It's pretty simple -- if the "ignorefile" exists in a target directory (DIR1, DIR2, DIR3, etc), my utility will add exclusions to the `zip -r DEST.zip DIR1` command using the pattern `-x some_file` or `-x some_dir/*`.

**The Issue**
I am running into an issue with directory exclusion, however, and I can't quite figure out why (*this is probably be because I am still quite the sh novice*). I'll run through some examples:

Let's say that I want to ignore two things in my project directory: `.git/*` and `.gitignore`. Running `command foo.zip project_dir` builds the following command:

`zip -r foo.zip project -x project/.git/\* -x project/.gitignore`

Woohoo! Success! Well... not quite.

In this example, `.gitignore` is not added to the compressed output file, `foo.zip`. The directory, `.git/*`, and all of it's subdirectories (and files)  **are** added to the compressed output file.

---

Manually running the command:

`zip -r foo.zip project_dir -x project/.git/\* -x project/.gitignore`

Works as expected, of course, so naturally I am pretty puzzled as to why my identical, but dynamically-built command, does not work.

**Attempted Resolutions**

I have attempted a few different methods of resolving this to no avail:

- Removing `-x project/.git/\*` from the command, and instead adding each subdirectory and file within that directory, such as `-x project/.git/config -x project/.git/HEAD`, etc (including children of subdirectories)
- Removing the backslash before the asterisk, so that the resulting exclusion option within the command is `-x project/.git/*`
- Bashing my head on the keyboard in angst (I'm really surprised this didn't work, it usually does)

---

**Some notes**

- My utility uses `/bin/sh`; I would prefer to keep it that way for maximum compatibility.
- I am aware of the `git archive` feature -- my use of `.git/*` and `.gitignore` in the above example is simply as an example; my utility is not dependent on git nor is used exclusively for projects which are git repositories.

Comment: How are you running your generated command? This is the key part, and not shown. Also, I appreciate your time to tell the full story, but for the next time just go directly to the problem. Questions need to be concise and direct.

Comment: @sidyll, the command is stored in a variable COMMAND, and is then executed using `$COMMAND` (I have also used `${COMMAND}`). You pointed me in the right direction and using `eval $COMMAND` works as expected. If you'd like to write an answer, I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for re-opening the question. Not because of points, but leaving it might be useful for future viewers that might run into similar problems. This is the great intention behind this site, maintaining a database of solutions. Best wishes Benjamin

Comment: Which is precisely the reason I leave robust descriptions ;) -- although being direct and concise is definitely preferable in most situations! Thanks again, and keep on rockin'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspected the problem would be in the evaluation of the generated command, since you said the same command when executed directly did right.

So as the comment section says, I think you already found the correct solution. This happens because if you run that variable directly, some things like globs can be expanded directly, instead of passed to the command. And arguments may be messed up, depending on the situation.

Yes, in that case:

```
eval $COMMAND
```

is the way to go.